# How to connect my monitor to intel i7 2700k integrated graphics?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, integrated-graphics

I am having problems with my PC and I'm trying to figure out if it's a GPU or PSU problem. I thought I'd remove the GPU entirely and use the intel graphics to make sure, but my motherboard (Sabertooth P67) doesn't seem to have any kind of port to connect the monitor to... Am I missing something?

Comment: Your motherboard doesn't have video out.

Comment: @vembutech That's unfortunate. Thanks for the reply. While you're here, do you know if the motherboard is compatible with gtx 1050 Ti?

Comment: @Moody - Does it have the appropriate PCI-E slot?  If you don't know off hand, the specifications for the Sabertooth P67, is on product page at the ASUS website.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, according to the website, it has the following slots: "2 x PCIe 2.0 x16 (x16 or dual x8),
3 x PCIe 2.0 x1,
1 x PCI"

Comment: @Moody You answered your own question then...

Answer (score 0):

Removing the GPU and relying on the internal one may not help rule out a PSU problem - if the GPU is drawing a significant amount of power it may actually be causing the problem with the PSU by drawing too much power.

You may be able to partially diagnose this by doing tests which stress test the system without doing a lot of intensive graphics (like using Prime95).  If the system dies or misbehaves the issue is not the GPU.

Comment: It is worth pointing out.  If the GPU worked at one point, then your PSU being the source of your problems, is very unlikely.  However, like any PCB an external GPU can stop functioning, when that happens you should replace them.

Comment: @davidgo Prime95 seems to be running fine. The problems come when I play a game (or run furmark). In very little time (less than a minute), the screen freezes with a lot of weird colours, then flashes and I get a message that the driver failed then recovered.

A couple of times it happened even though I'm not playing anything, just browsing the net. I really don't know if the culprit is the GPU or PSU.

(PS: Should I make a new thread about this?)

Comment: It sounds very much like the GPU from your description here